# Angular 5 and ExcelJS

Tags: angular, angular5, exceljs

I have been trying to use and following the examples from this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#create-a-workbook

I am using it on Angular 5.
I always get an error

```
graceful-fs.js:166 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at patch (graceful-fs.js:166)
```

From these lines of my code:

```
import * as Excel from 'exceljs';

export class ExcelHandler {
   public testExcelJs() {
      var workBook: Excel.Workbook;
      var workSheet: Excel.Worksheet;

      workBook = new Excel.Workbook();
      workSheet = workBook.addWorksheet(sheetName);
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the npm example is given in node definitions and you are using typescript, a quick workaround would be to install node types so that you needn't find equivalent typescript syntax everytime, ie **`npm install --save-dev @types/node`**, with this done, node definitions would be added to the IDE and would also resolve compilation issues.

Now your file could be like this:

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');


export class ExcelHandler {
   public testExcelJs() {


      var workBook = new Excel.Workbook();
      var workSheet = workBook.addWorksheet('my-worksheet');
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the error being displayed? is it the same thing?

Comment: I created this typescript file and compilation doesn't give me any errors, what exactly is the issue that you are facing? could you post your code snippet in https://stackblitz.com and share the url