# ExcelJS/Angular type error when trying to change borders

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, exceljs

I'm using [excelJS](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) in an Angular 4 project. When I try to change the borders from a particular row, like so:

```
sheet.getRow(5).eachCell(cell => cell.border = {
    top: { style: 'thin' },
    left: { style: 'thin' },
    bottom: { style: 'thin' },
    right: { style: 'thin' }
});
```

I get the following error on angular compiler:

`Type '{ top: { style: string; }; left: { style: string; }; bottom: { style: string; }; right: { style: ...' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Borders>'.`

**Edit:**
I previously had the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088876/angular-5-and-exceljs) and the solution didn't work. Someone also recomended to simply `npm install --save-dev @types/exceljs`. But it didn't work also so I've used [this solution](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/issues/511#issuecomment-391140701), and added the following to my `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "exceljs": [
        "../node_modules/exceljs/dist/es5/exceljs.browser"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Works for me.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-u4lvp4

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir this code has only a hello world

Comment: My bad, forgot to press save, should be there now

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir There's an import error now (`can't find file: ./zlib_bindings`)

Comment: @user184994 .. mkay .. works on my machine .. I actually tried it in VS code first and it worked .. my stackbliz reproduction   seems to be bad..

Comment: Stackbliz is a ts compiler and it's not using angular. I'm not sure, but maybe this has something to do with `@types/exceljs`, I'll update the question with this

Answer (score 1):

After some thought I was able to make this work. But the solution feels dirty. A workaround that bypassed the types in the compiler and worked was using `Object.assign`:

```
sheet.getRow(5).eachCell(cell => Object.assign(cell, {
    border: {
        top: { style: 'thin' },
        left: { style: 'thin' },
        bottom: { style: 'thin' },
        right: { style: 'thin' }
    })
});
```